# The value of ebx register changes after executing "mov eax, [edx+ebx]" Assembly (NASM)

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am new in assembly and I am trying to do some arbitrary precision arithmethic in assembly. But I am stuck in an error for a whole day.

```
    mov eax,[ebp+8] ; the first parameter of c function
    mov edx,[ebp+12] ; the second parameter of c function
    sub ecx,ecx
    sub ebx,ebx

    for_loop2:
    cmp ecx,[noktadanSonraFark] ; [noktadanSonraFark] is a variable that contains the difference of the lenghts of the two parameters 
    je end_for2

    mov ebx,[length2] ; the length of the second parameter "9"

    sub ebx,1 ; if length is 9 the last chacter will be on 8. index

    sub ebx,ecx

    mov eax, [edx+ebx] ; must show the character at the 8.index

        mov eax,ebx ; this 4 line returns thee value stored in eax to the 
        pop ebx  ; c function. and the result is printed
        pop ebp
        ret

    inc ecx
    jmp for_loop2
```

My problem is that nothing is printed to the screen. But when I comment this line `mov eax, [edx+ebx]`the ebx value is printed correctly "8" So it seems that this line `mov eax, [edx+ebx]`  changes the value in ebx or deletes it. Because nothing is printed to the screen. Any ideas?

Comment: Why the two MOVs into EAX on adjacent lines?

Comment: Because with the ret command, the value in eax is returned to the caller function. In our case it is a c function which prints the result of eax. I want to see the value in ebx register there for I mov it to eax and then return. But normally I wont need the four lines starting with mov eax,ebx. I will delete them when I see the value in ebx is right. So I use it just for debugging

Comment: Is the return of this supposed to be a character or integer? If you are returning the number 8 when a character is expected, you won't see any output. (A simple hack to convert a number from 0-9 to a character is to add 48)

Comment: There's two "pop"s at the end of the function. I assume the function prolog has matching "push"s? Otherwise, that's why you're getting weird results - stack corruption.

Comment: @John: That depends on the calling convention. With stdcall calling convention, the called function is expected to clean up the stack. So if two DWORD parameters were passed in, then you'd want to pop two DWORDs from the stack before returning.

Comment: No, it's missing the prolog. Somewhere ebp will be set from esp, e.g "push ebp; mov ebp, esp". This is either chopped because Alptugay didn't deem it important, or it's really missing and that'll be the cause of the problem.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw I am already adding 48. @John The number of push and pop are equal. And when I just comment one line from the code (the mov eax, [edx+ebx] line ) it works correctly. So I dont think there is a problem with the stack. Btw my function starts with `push ebp  ; save esp register
 mov  ebp, esp  ; get current stack pointer
 push ebx  ; save ebx register`

Comment: @Alptugay: Do you have the ability to single-step this code in a debugger? That way you'll be able to look at each register before each instruction is executed, and you'll be able to find out exactly where the problem is. I would encourage you to carefully examine what's in the `edx` register, as I believe that's where you'll find the problem.

Comment: I have found the problem. My problem is that I wanted to declare the variables as doubleword so I used `dw`. But I have learned that to declare a doubleword variable `dd` needs to be used. I think it is dw in masm but dd in nasm. I am not sure though

Comment: No, `db` is "define byte", `dw` is "define word" (16 bits), and `dd` is "define dword". In both masm and nasm.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely the problem is that the instruction `mov eax, [edx+ebx]` is trying to access a memory address that your program doesn't have permission to access. That causes the program to crash. Thus, no output. It's certain that accessing `[edx+ebx]` does not modify either of those two registers.

You say that if you comment out that line, things work as expected and the output is "8", which is the value of `ebx`. Have you checked the value of `edx`?